# PHP Foreach statement issue. Multiple rows are returned

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm a PHP beginner and lately I've been having a problem with my source code.

Here it is:

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Bot
        </title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="bot.php "method="post">
            <lable>You:<input type="text" name="intrebare"></lable>
            <input type="submit" name="introdu" value="Send">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("robo") or die(mysql_error());

$intrebare=$_POST['intrebare'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM dialog where intrebare like '%$intrebare%'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
?>
<div id="history">
<?php       
        foreach($row as $rows){ 
            echo "<b>The robot says: </b><br />";
            echo $row['raspuns'];
            }
?>
</div>
```

It returns the result 6x times.

This problem appeared when I've made that `foreach` because I wanted the results to stuck on the page one by one after every SQL query.

Can you please tell me what seems to be the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. ;-)

First of all you have to fetch your result with `mysql_fetch_array` in a loop like this:

```
while (true == ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))) {
    echo "<b>The robot says: </b><br />";
    echo $row['raspuns'];
}
```

Second I want to tell you that all mysql_* functions are marked as deprecated. If you want to learn PHP you should try to learn how to connect to mysql using PDO.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked, thanks. But it still returning me the result and then it replaces it with next one. I want to keep all the results on the page. Can you tell me please how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_fetch_array` fetches one row per call.  You'll want to do like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<b>The robot says:</b><br>";
    echo htmlentities($row['raspuns']);
}
```

and get rid of that first `mysql_fetch_array`.

(Notice that i am HTML-escaping the variable output.  Unless you know what you're doing, you should not output raw data into a page.)

By the way, `mysql_query` is effectively deprecated.  It is not at all recommended for new code.  Take a look at mysqli (the replacement) or PDO (the new hotness).  With the new mysqli (objecty) interface, the PHP part would look a bit like this:

```
<?php

//error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'robo');

# turn into a wildcard
$intrebare='%' . $_POST['intrebare'] . '%';

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM dialog WHERE intrebare LIKE ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $intrebare);
$result = $stmt->execute();

echo '<div id="history">';
# 5.4 lets you do it like this; 
# older versions, try `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())`
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo "<b>The robot says: </b><br />";
    echo htmlentities($row['raspuns']);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying it reversed way:

```
    <?php     

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){ 
        echo '<strong>The robot says: </strong><br />', $row['raspuns'];
        }
    ?>
```

Try now :)

Comment: Let me rephrase the foreach loop in plain English. For each of the $row from the $rows.... echo a $row. Helps?

Comment: I was the downvoter; `mysql_fetch_array($result)` only fetches one row at a time. Therefore, with only one call to it, your foreach loop is only iterating through the first row.

Comment: Almost; check your parentheses :)

Comment: Just added it though was optional. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use while to fetch all the data and check variable names

```
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
        echo "<b>The robot says: </b><br />";
        echo $row['raspuns']; // Here
        }
```

Comment: @BenjaminPaap - $row IS an array; it was just being set only once

Comment: @MTahir - Count your parentheses

Comment: @GlaciesofPacis: Thanks, I was hasty and missed the details earlier

Answer (score 1):

You're only getting one result (only one call to mysql_fetch_array()). There are six columns, I bet, in dialog.

```
...
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
?>
<div id="history">
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<b>The robot says: </b><br />";
    echo htmlentities($row['raspuns']);
}
?>
</div>
```

Also, mysql_* functions are being deprecated. Switch to mysqli_* or PDO.